# 15" MacBook Pro freezes

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

My 15" MacBook Pro, running macOS Sierra freezes frequently. This happens randomly, it freezes and only a force-shutdown (hold the power button) works. First, the Beachball just spins, then sometimes a black screen appears without any description or explanation. At this point, other buttons do not respond.

I tried DiskUtil, CleanMyMac and OnyX to check the SSD, tried reparing permissions and other decisions. But my MacBook continues to hang, although now a little less.

Please recommend me other programs for testing and troubleshooting. Is my MacBook dying? Which devices can cause this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a kernel panic, crash, or system dialogue that might help us help you troubleshoot? There are a lot of possibilities and logs help narrow down those possibilities and provide solutions.

Comment: What Mac model?

Comment: Console.app lets you look at logs, there might be a hint.

Answer (score 1):

First, back up all the data on your Mac with Time Machine, [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html), etc.

Second, create an installer of macOS Sierra (latest version) with [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com) or other tools.

Third, reinstall macOS Sierra with the installer, but don't erase the hard disk your Mac. All settings and data will still be there as before.

Just to see if the issue occurs again or not. Try to erase your hard disk and reinstall macOS Sierra, if it happens again. Remember to back up all your files before the operation.

Comment: I already tried reinstalling. But I want to try again with full formatting hard drive.

Comment: I reinstalled the system. so far, the freezes were not. I hope this has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your mac is not dying but it need some investigation. usually any device freezes if you consume all resources. check activity monitor which process consume your CPU, Memory, Energy, Disk and Network.

once you identify the process you may do the required repair. may be it is unused application and bug in application used. in both cases try to remove it before trying any other debugging method.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a defective RAM module. Try to run the extended memory test from the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257). Depending on your model the procedure differs. To enter the diagnostics mode you typically press the D key before the boot screen appears.

Comment: I tried this method. no error detected.